# Makefile: object and dependency files

Tags: c, makefile

I divide all the `.C` codes into two groups, one is `A1_SRC` and the other is `A2_SRC`. Both groups share the same header codes `const.h` and `var.h`. I attach my Makefile below:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

EXEC=../bin
OBJ=../obj

CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -traceback
LFLAGS=-lm -lfftw3 -lstdc++ -lmpi

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $*.c > $(OBJ)/$*.d

A1_OBJ = $(A1_SRC:%.c=%.o)
A2_OBJ = $(A2_SRC:%.c=%.o)

A1_SRC = \
        test.c \
        alloc.c \
        func.c

A2_SRC = \
        test1.c \
        test2.c

A1: $(A1_OBJ) const.h var.h
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A1_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A1

A2: $(A2_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A2_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A2

all: A1 A2

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o $(OBJ)/*.d $(EXEC)/* 

install: clean all

-include $(A1_OBJ:.o=.d)
-include $(A2_OBJ:.o=.d)
```

Here are my questions:

1. I know `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $*.c > $(OBJ)/$*.d` is used to generate dependency files. But can it be run under `%.o: %.c`? Is this a correct usage?
2. I'd like `.o` files also store at `$(OBJ)` directory (same for `.d` files). How can I add this command to Makefile?
3. Compared with `A1: $(A1_OBJ) const.h var.h`, why `A2: $(A2_OBJ)` does not have `const.h var.h` behind it?
4. Could the last 2 lines `-include $(A1_OBJ:.o=.d)` and `-include $(A2_OBJ:.o=.d)` be combined into 1 line using some tricks?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) It can be done, with a little effort. 3) This looks like an oversight. 4) Yes. Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: @Beta Fully understand your point. Since these questions are all related to one Makefile with some advanced usage, they will be very useful to readers if people search object files or dependent files, or would like to mimic an example Makefile for their purpose. Could you answer my questions if you know how to? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I recommend you read https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ and see if it provides any helpful insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I know `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $*.c > $(OBJ)/$*.d` is used to generate dependency files. But can it be run under `%.o: %.c`? Is this a correct usage?

Yes.  It is best suited for that context, in fact.  The GNU `make` manual recommends against using `$*` outside an implicit rule (of which pattern rules are the prime example).

> 2. I'd like `.o` files also store at `$(OBJ)` directory (same for `.d` files). How can I add this command to Makefile?

In the first place, you *shouldn't*.  If you want an out-of-source build then use VPATH.  Otherwise, why spend time and effort to complicate your makefile and make it harder to maintain?

But if you must, then understand that `make` has no separation between a file and the directory that contains it.  You can't change the directory in which a file is built -- you must instead build a different file.  In particular, if you want your `.o` files to be built in directory `$(OBJ)`, then first, change the `%.o: %.c` rule to a `$(OBJ)/%.o: %.c` rule.  And second, change the definitions of your `A1_OBJS` and `A2_OBJS` rules so that they expend to lists of files in `$(OBJ)`.

> 3. Compared with `A1: $(A1_OBJ) const.h var.h`, why `A2: $(A2_OBJ)` does not have `const.h var.h` behind it?

You said it's *your* makefile.  You tell me.

Possibly it's a mistake.  Possibly the A2 sources do not depend on those headers.  Possibly the second rule is relying on your automatic dependency generation, but the first one hasn't gotten the message yet.

> 4. Could the last 2 lines `-include $(A1_OBJ:.o=.d)` and `-include $(A2_OBJ:.o=.d)` be combined into 1 line using some tricks?

I dunno. Do you consider this ...

```
-include $(A1_OBJ:.o=.d) $(A2_OBJ:.o=.d)
```

... to involve tricks?

The `include` directive expects a list of file names to process.  It doesn't matter what mechanism you use to specify those.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. If I want to include the path of `.o` and `.d` files, can I write the last line as `-include $(A1_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d) $(A2_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d)`  @John Bollinger

Comment: Have you tried that, @ThomasD?  Even if it worked, why would you prefer that over the alternative presented in this answer?