# Makefile: fail to compile and link due to missing separator error

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, intel-mpi

I wrote a Makefile to compile my C source codes and generate `.o`, `.d` files which aim to be stored at another directory different from where the source `.c` codes reside. Here is a copy of my Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

EXEC=./bin
OBJ=./obj

CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall
LFLAGS=-lm -lstdc++ -lmpi


$(OBJ)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $*.c > $(OBJ)/$*.d


FWI_OBJ = $(FWI_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ)/%.o)

FWI_SRC = \
        testmpi.c \
        printneigh.c


fwi2D:      $(FWI_OBJ) fd.h
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(FWI_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/xtestmpi

all: fwi2D

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o $(OBJ)/*.d $(EXEC)/*

install: clean all

-include $(FWI_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d)
```

After I `make` it, the screen shows the error message below:

```
obj/testmpi.o:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
obj/testmpi.o:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Could anyone help debug this Makefile and figure out why it happened?

Comment: This question is highly reminiscent of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454485/makefile-object-and-dependency-files) from yesterday.  In particular, the OP of that question asks in comments about exactly the (erroneous) form of `include` statement that appears in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
> -include $(FWI_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d)
> ```

... is wrong.  The substitution reference attempts to convert file names from `$(FWI_OBJ)` that end with `$(OBJ)/.o` (as expanded) to end instead with `$(OBJ)/.d` (as expanded).  None of the file names in `$(FWI_OBJ)` end that way, so they all pass through unchanged.  As a result, `make` tries to `include` the `.o` files, not the `.d` files you wanted.

Probably you meant this, instead:

```
-include $(FWI_OBJ:.o=.d)
```

Comment: Thanks, @John Bollinger. I tried your strategy and it works. Awesome!